# Current JsonReader item is not an array

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

Why isn't this recognized as Json, and how to fix it?

From : https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd

```
{"ticker":{"base":"BTC","target":"USD","price":"15280.38154311",
"volume":"79294.04151102","change":"127.22487796"},
"timestamp":1514038983,"success":true,"error":""}


var array = JArray.Load(reader);
```

**Exception**: Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an array.

Comment: That's correct. It isn't an array. There is no array in your JSON. An array is denoted by `[` and `]`.

Comment: it is an object, not an array

Comment: It's not an array :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `JObject.Load(reader)`.

A JSON array is wrapped in `[ ]` whereas `{ }` indicates an object.